# Get dynamic number parameter in php from url

Tags: php

I'm trying to get numbers automatically in php from url ,

**Like this :**

```
http://127.0.0.1/+/number/?p=123
http://127.0.0.1/+/number/?p=2599
```

...

**When i change the (number) from url**

```
http://127.0.0.1/+/number/?p=111
```

**I want to print :**

```
111
```

[image]

Comment: See [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    echo $_GET['p'];
?>
```

Comment: Thanks :) , But howa can i create a php page like ?p=123 with dynamic request

Comment: you need to learn about url rewriting, which can be achieved by enabling mod_rewrite module in your php settings

Answer (score 1):

Do:

```
echo $_GET['p'];
```

`p` being whatever is between `?` and `=`. I mean, to print `1` from `/?col=1` do:

```
echo $_GET['col'];
```